# TeX Live Manager Error

Tags: errors, texlive-2019

After updating some packages I am receiving this error:

> Error: can't read "::active_cls": no such variable

How can this be corrected? I uninstalled TeX Live and reinstalled, and received the same error.

Comment: I did have the same problem today with a fresh install of TeX Live on windows 10. The command line tool still works for me tough. So I'd say for you to use tlmgr in a terminal for the time being.

Comment: I have the same error and now it does not even open texlive manager.

Comment: See https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2019-July/043817.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Where are the installer files found so that I can replace it? Regards.

Comment: @azetina that email link is all I know, sorry:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David Carlisle, I was able to use the link he provided to do a quick patch of the files. Below are the steps to follow to fix the issue:

1. Go to [tug.org/texlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).
2. Click on [download](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and [sources for the current release](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Source/). This will take you to your closest CTAN mirror.
3. Click on `texlive/` then `tlnet/` then `tlpkg/` then `tltcl/` and download the files.
4. Replace these in your texlive 2019 folder in the sub directory `C:\texlive\2019\tlpkg\tltcl`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when trying to run TeXLive manager. 
It was solved by updating the manager through command line by the command

```
tlmgr update --self
```

If the above command does not solve the problem, try the following command

```
tlmgr update --all
```

this should clear and update the error causing packages.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem occurs only with the GUI `tlshell` (Tcl/Tk-based) for tlmgr.

If you have java, I think the java-based `tlcockpit` (another GUI for tlmgr) under the directory `\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\tlcockpit\tlcockpit.jar` might be a better alternative.

Hope it helpful :)